# Remote server - "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them

Tags: r, bash, command-line, cloud

I am having some troubles reconnecting to a session I was working on. This is the first time I was doing it and I seem to have been kicked out of the session while the system is still running on remote.

I connect to WinSCP to a server from my university. Then I open the command line and type the server, username and password. Once inside I write "screen -D -R" and I can run R directly from the command line.

Here are the steps I took:

1) I was doing my R code and suddenly I pressed some keys that caused **"\Quit (core dumped)"**. It kicked me out of the program and send me to the bash shell.
2) I tried "screen -D -R" as I had done before to enter appeared the question: "Attaching from inside of screen"?
3) Here I did not know what to do so I pressed "y" but it started printing "y"s like crazy, so I closed the shell window.
4) When I did screen -list, at the beginning I only saw one open session in status attached, after trying many things I just made things worse and now I have 4 session and cannot enter any. 
4) I looked on the internet for several hours and typed many things like:

1. screen -rd
2. screen -d -r 7315.tty.host
3. screen -r 22106.7315
4. screen -x
5. screen -d -r 7315.pts-0.polo
6. screen [-d] -r [7315.]tty.host

As you can see, I am a complete rookie. I attach a screenshot.

[image]

**QUESTION:**

a) How can I enter my R program again?

b) I do not mind losing everything I had so if it is not possible, how do I close everything I opened and reopen from 0?

Answer (score 1):

I came back just to say I was able to find a way around it.

1. screen -list
2. screen -d "name_of_each_session" (to detach all)
3. screen -S "name_of_each_session" -p 0 -X quit (to close all except
           the one I wanted)
4. screen -D -R (to enter the one I wanted)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or even simplier:

`screen -d -r 99999`

where 99999 is the name of one of the sessions and work from there as usual (next, previous, exit, etc.)